# Django User-Login and authentication is not working

Tags: python, django, user-interface, authentication

I am creating a simple user-login page using Django and after get login redirecting to home page.But its always redirecting to unauthorized option given in app's views.py (i.e Invalid Details). Please check and help me.

Project name:login and App name: index

```
views.py


from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username', '')
    password = request.GET.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
            else:
                    return HttpResponse("Bad request")
    else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid details")

  @login_required
  def home(request):
       return render_to_response('home.html') 


 App urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
   url(r'^auth/$', views.auth, name='auth'),
  url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
]


Project's: urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('index.urls')),
  ]
```

Templates:

```
 login.html

 {% block content %}

 {% if form.errors %}
<p class="error">Sorry, that's not a valid username or password</p>
{% endif %}

 <form action="/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <label for="username">User name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

 <input type="submit" value="login" />
 <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
 </form>

{% endblock %}

home.html

{% block content %}

<h1>Hello Vivek</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to share another approach to manage authentication in django assuming you already have a login html template (with username and password inputs inside a form with post action) , a user form and a home template , this would be the authentication views .py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from ..form import UsersForm


class LoginView(View):

    template_name = ['yourtemplatedirectory/login.html', 'yourtemplatedirectory/home.html']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UsersForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, self.template_name[1])
        return render(request, self.template_name[0])

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.is_active:
                return render(request, self.template_name[ 1 ])
        else:
            messages.add_message(
                request, messages.ERROR, "Invalid username or password"
                )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse( 'yourapp:login' ))


def LogoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse( 'yourapp:home' ))
```

Just call the respective url from login and logout buttons and that's it. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
username = request.GET.get('username', '')
password = request.GET.get('password', '')
```

to

```
username = request.POST.get('username', '')
password = request.POST.get('password', '')
```

Comment: its also good to do debug mode on your ide - we can quickly see if username or password has any value at all. Or you can simple print it out on your terminal

Comment: Bro thanks for reply but if you're thinking that I didn't try this method then you are wrong..as already tried with all general methods but getting failed so posted here..:)..BTW thanks